# Using を with verbs?

Tags: particle-を, formality

I was studying on certain phrases NOT to say in Japan (in particular, not using を before 何{なに}) and then examples were given using/not using を. This confused me, especially before a verb. These were two examples I was given:

> お茶{ちゃ}いっぱい飲{の}んだ。
>
> お茶{ちゃ}をいっぱい飲{の}みました。

Obviously the first one is informal vs the next one being formal, but does that have anything to do with the use of を? Or is it because you can not use を directly in front of a verb? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Obviously the first one is informal vs the next one being formal, but does that have anything to do with the use of を?

I think the informal version just drops the を due to casual laziness.

> Or is it because you can not use を directly in front of a verb?

There is no such restriction.